# Maximizing according to a function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that accepts a function and two inputs, and returns the argument that maximizes the function. This is the setup I want to use:

```
max :: Eq a => (a -> Int) -> a -> a -> a
```

For example, the function should work as follows:

```
maximize (+3) 5 10 = 10
```

Because (3+5) < (3+10)

I am thinking I need to do something like this:

```
maximize :: Eq a => (a -> Int) -> a -> a -> a
maximize f x y = max (f x) (f y)
```

This approach doesn't seem to be working though. Thank you for any help!

Comment: `maximize f x y = maximumBy (comparing f) [x,y]`

Comment: Note that the `Eq a` constraint doesn't do anything useful for you. You don't need to check if the arguments are equal, all you need to compare is the results, so you might as well omit that constraint. You could however make it also polymorphic on the _result_ of the function, and then you'd need such a constraint there – but `Eq` is not enough, you'd need `Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> a`.

Comment: Where are we on this question ? did you receive your answer ?

Comment: I did, thank you! Managed to get the function working

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that `max (f x) (f y)` gives back either `f x` or `f y`, as opposed to either `x` or `y`. You have to compare the former pair of values and then return one of the latter. One way of doing that is using [`compare`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:compare) and then pattern matching on its result, like this:

```
-- You don't actually need the `Eq a` constraint here.
maximize :: (a -> Int) -> a -> a -> a
maximize f x y = case compare (f x) (f y) of
    -- etc. (I will let you fill in the details.)
```

One shortcut for writing that is using [`comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) from `Data.Ord`, which allows you to replace `compare (f x) (f y)` with `comparing f x y`. A further shortcut, suggested above by user2407038, uses [`maximumBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy) from `Data.List` to reduce it all to the one-liner `maximumBy (comparing f) [x,y]`.

Comment: ``comparing = (compare `on`)``, a pattern that can be used much more generally.

Answer (score 6):

How about the straightforward implementation:

```
maximize f x y = if (f x) > (f y) then x else y
```

Comment: Nice one. This is, of course, exactly equivalent to the `compare` solution, given that `(>)` can be expressed in terms of a case analysis of the result of `compare` and that if-then-else is just syntax sugar over case analysis on `Bool` -- and yet this way of writing it might look a little more intuitive to an absolute beginner. That no one else had event mentioned it yet shows how much instinctive bias against if-then-else there is around here :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
maximize f x y = argmax f [x,y]
```

but this requires installing the [list-extras package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-extras-0.4.1.4/docs/Data-List-Extras-Argmax.html).

However, I think the other answers are more idiomatic (@duplode) and simpler (@Uri Goren).

Answer (score 0):

A different, yet very simple, approach using guards:

```
maxiM :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> a
maxiM func v1 v2
  | (func v1) < (func v2)       = (func v2)
  | otherwise                   = (func v1)
```

I suggest looking at learnyouahaskell.

Comment: The `Ord a` constraint is redundant. Use `Ord b` and `a -> b` as leftaroundabout suggests.