# Implementing argmax in Haskell

Tags: python, haskell

Given a list `L` , and a function `f`, I want to return an item `x` from `L` that maximizes the value of `f(x)`

I cam up with this code for 2 variables:

```
argmax f x y = if (f x) > (f y) then x else y
```

How can this be generalized to

```
argmax f [x,y,z]
```

(With an arbitrary number of items in the list)

This is what I would do in `Python`:

```
argmax = lambda f,L: max([(f(x),x) for x in L])[1] if len(L)>0 else None
```

How can I apply the same logic in `Haskell` ?

Comment: Looks like you're not familiar with handling lists. Google. Then, if neccesary, ask a real question.

Comment: Look up the function `maximum` and see if you can do the same thing using a Haskell list comprehension: `[(f x, x) | x <- values]`.  How would you handle returning the Haskell equivalent of `None` if the `values` list is empty?  What would be the full type of your `argmax` function in Haskell?

Comment: The equivalent of python's `None` would be using a `Maybe`m yet how do I sort tuples according to their first parameter ?

Comment: The `maximumBy` solution in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40209169/2751851) generalises to lists of arbitrary size. There is also an `argmax` provided by a library mentioned there.

Comment: Hint: use `map`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I fail to get that hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer -- I've been learning Haskell (functional paradigm in general) for a week now so it's likely there are better solutions.

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

argmax f l 
    | null l = error "Given list is empty"
    | otherwise = maximumBy (comparing f) l
```

Comment: can `[(fst arg, f $ snd arg) | arg <- zip l l]` be replaced with `[(x, f x) | x <- l]` for brevity ?

Comment: `maximumBy (comparing f) l` is equivalent to your `otherwise` case.

Comment: @UriGoren I think your suggestion would work as well but duplode's suggestion is cleaner.

Comment: You can lose the first clause, too. `maximumBy` errors if the list is empty.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I agree. One of the comments in the question asked "how would you handle the situation if the list is empty.." so I added it for no particular reason.

Comment: Three other ways of handling that situation: returning a `Maybe`-value, taking the first value to be compared as a separate argument, using [`NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) instead of a plain old list.