# How can I compare elements of two lists according to one predicate and select according to another?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

What I am trying to achieve is to compare two lists of tuples with `` ((==) `on` fst) `` and out of the pairs that satisfy this predicate, select the ones that satisfy `` (min `on` snd) ``

Comment: Check out [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html). You're looking for `groupBy` and `minimumBy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve a general case, you can define modified version of filter that pattern-matches a tuple containing two predicates and checks if both are satisfied.

```
filter' :: ((a->Bool),(a->Bool)) -> [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
filter' (pred1,pred2) = foldr f []
 where f = (\x acc -> if pred1 $ fst x then
                                        if pred2 $ snd x then x : acc
                                        else acc
                      else acc
           )
```

Which would evaluate a list `[(1,2),(2,2),(3,3),(3,4)]` with the first predicate `odd` and the second predicate `even` as:

```
>> filter' (odd,even) [(1,2),(2,2),(3,3),(3,4)]
[(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Comment: Rebuilding a list with `foldl` by appending single elements with `(++)` is not a good idea -- use `foldr` and `(:)` instead. Furthermore, there is no need to reimplement the whole thing. You can reuse `filter` just fine, with something like `filter' p q = filter (uncurry (&&) . bimap p q)`.

Comment: Good point. Changed my implementation to use `foldr`, though what you've included is better/more concise.

Comment: What is the `bimap` function you are using?

Comment: It is in `Data.Bifunctor`, and can be used to map two different functions to e.g. each component of an `(a, b)` pair or each case of `Either a b`.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that...

> What I am trying to achieve is to compare two lists of tuples with `` ((==) `on` fst) ``

... means comparing each pair in one list with the corresponding pair in the other list, as in the usual `(==)` for lists.

Here is a mostly pointfree (and perhaps slightly cranky) solution that stays close to your original suggestions:

```
-- Suggestions of sensible names for this are welcome.
yourSelector :: (Eq a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
yourSelector ps = fmap (minBy' snd)
    . filter (uncurry ((==) `on` fst)) . zip ps
    where
    minBy' f (x, y) = case (compare `on` f) x y of
        LT -> x
        _ -> y
```

```
GHCi> yourSelector [(1,2),(3,5),(4,7)] [(1,3),(2,2),(4,9)]
[(1,2),(4,7)]
```

For alternative ways of writing `minBy'`, cf. [*Maximizing according to a function*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40209169/2751851).